# Not getting the countdown feature in my webpage

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I am making a contest platform ..For it I need a countdown timer ..The problem is that I donno JS ..So I googled up and got this script for the timer..But It is not working in the webpage...Please help me out..
Here is the code for the timer...I am getting the box for the div tag but not the timer in it...Please help me coz I am complete new bie in JS..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>CoBo:Contest</title>
        <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script>
          function start(myD, myH, myMins, mySecs, myL) {
              var d = new Date();//  Returns the Day (number) so we can set it to default
              currentDay = d.getDate();
              var month = 0;//  '*' for next month, '0' for this month or 1 through 12 for the month 
              var day = myD;//  Offset for day of month day or + day  
              var hour = myH;//  0 through 23 for the hours of the day
              var minutes = myMins;//  Minutes of the hour to End on
              var seconds = mySecs;//  Seconds of the minute to End on
              var tz =  - 7;//  Offset for your timezone in hours from UTC
              var lab = myL;//  The id of the page entry where the timezone countdown is to show
              displayTZCountDown(setTZCountDown(month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, tz), lab);
          }

          function setTZCountDown(month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, tz) {
              var toDate = new Date();
              if (month == '*')
                  toDate.setMonth(toDate.getMonth() + 1);
              else if (month > 0) {
                  if (month <= toDate.getMonth())
                      toDate.setYear(toDate.getYear() + 1);
                  toDate.setMonth(month - 1);
              }
              if (day.substr(0, 1) == '+') {
                  var day1 = parseInt(day.substr(1));
                  toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate() + day1);
              }
              else {
                  toDate.setDate(day);
              }
              toDate.setHours(hour);
              toDate.setMinutes(minutes - (tz * 60));
              toDate.setSeconds(seconds);
              var fromDate = new Date();
              fromDate.setMinutes(fromDate.getMinutes() + fromDate.getTimezoneOffset());
              var diffDate = new Date(0);
              diffDate.setMilliseconds(toDate - fromDate);
              return Math.floor(diffDate.valueOf() / 1000);
          }

          function displayTZCountDown(countdown, tzcd) {
              if (countdown < 0)
              document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = "<b>Ended</b>";
              else {
                  var secs = countdown % 60;
                  if (secs < 10)
                  secs = '0' + secs;
                  var countdown1 = (countdown - secs) / 60;
                  var mins = countdown1 % 60;
                  if (mins < 10)
                  mins = '0' + mins;
                  countdown1 = (countdown1 - mins) / 60;
                  var hours = countdown1 % 24;
                  var days = (countdown1 - hours) / 24;
                  if (hours < 10) {
                      var hours = "0" + hours;
                  }
                  document.write(hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs);
                  document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;
                  setTimeout('displayTZCountDown(' + (countdown - 1) + ',\'' + tzcd + '\');', 999);
              }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar-top">
            <div id="inner">
                <script>
                          start('9', '25', '12', '00', '00', 'myTimerID');
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To help us answer your question you might want to read the FAQ(http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and see if you can't make your question more general and easier to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your script, it seems your HTML is missing an element with ID 'myTimerID'

Comment: I want to show it in div id="sidebar-top" "inner" ..What should I do ..I am not getting the output even when I replace myTimerID with sidebar-top

Comment: made some modifications, it's not really clear what the script is supposed to do or what you want it to do... but here's a working sample: 
[link](http://jsbin.com/orikos/3/edit#javascript,html)     |    you need to put the id in your html somewhere, and I had to fix some javascript typo's

Answer (score 0):

Btw I just made it perfect and small..Just pass the differnce of the target and present epoch times to the function and it gives the result :)

```
function displayTZCountDown(countdown, tzcd) {
            if (countdown < 0) {
                document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = "Ended";
                window.location="../contest.php";
            }
            else {
                var secs = countdown % 60;
                if (secs < 10) secs = '0' + secs;
                var countdown1 = (countdown - secs) / 60;
                var mins = countdown1 % 60;
                if (mins < 10) mins = '0' + mins;
                countdown1 = (countdown1 - mins) / 60;
                var hours = countdown1 % 24;
                var days = (countdown1 - hours) / 24;
                if (hours < 10) {
                    hours = "0" + hours;
                }
                document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = hours + ':' + mins + ':' + secs;
                setTimeout('displayTZCountDown(' + (countdown - 1) + ',\'' + tzcd + '\');', 999);
            }
        }
```

Here tzcd is the html id where I want to write and countdown is targetepoch-currentepoch